# safe place to put turtle settings?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

i have been tinkering this code to act as a screensaver, however; i have been having a issue of 1 pixel display; i need to put the turtle pen size up but there is no place to put it without failing on startup; i have tried at the top, middle and bottom to no avail.

```
from turtle import *
import random
from random import randint # from the random module import the function randint
#like turtle it is a module, read ahead for use

speed(9999999)

bgcolor('black')


x = 1

while x < 40099999999999999:

    r = randint(0,255) #makes variables r,g,b whose value is an integer,
    g = randint(0,255) # which is between 0 and 255. It is random, and
    b = randint(0,255) # changes every time the loop runs

    colormode(255) # this is something that is irrelevant at this point - unless you are using python 2.

    pencolor(r,g,b) # changes the color of the pen to the rgb coordinates
                    # obtained by the variables r, g, b changing each time

    fd(random.random() + random.randrange(99) * random.random())
    rt(90)#V1.1 - removed the random for this module - no reason to have random for the same number - wastes cpu power.


    x = x+1
```

thanks; amdcrash.

Comment: What did you try exactly and how did it failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're asking how to make the line thicker.  It would help if you supply the original code that you're modifying along with your version.  I believe this does what you describe and fixes other issues with the code:

```
from turtle import *
from random import random, randrange

speed('fastest')

width(3)  # "i need to put the turtle pen size up"

bgcolor('black')

colormode(255)

for x in range(1_000_000):

    r = randrange(256) # makes variables r,g,b whose value is an integer,
    g = randrange(256) # which is between 0 and 255. It is random, and
    b = randrange(256) # changes every time the loop runs

    pencolor(r, g, b) # changes the color of the pen to the rgb coordinates

    forward(random() + randrange(99) * random())

    right(90)
```

[image]